# How to code a double navbar with bootstrap?

Tags: css, vue.js, bootstrap-4

Could someone please help me with this, I'm trying to create the following:

[image]

With the below code:

```html
<header>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</header>

<body>
<div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3" style="padding-left: 11rem;">
  <div class="p-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que Buscas?"> </div>
  <div class="p-2"> <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ciudad"> </div>
  <div class="p-2"> <button type="button" class="btn bg-danger text-white">Buscar</button> </div>
</div>
</body>
```

I´ve ben trying to create this by using BootStrap´s classes.

Comment: Hello, have you already tried something, can we have the code?

Comment: hello, this is my best try,

<div class="d-flex flex-row mb-3" style="padding-left: 11rem;">
              <div class="p-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="¿Que Buscas?">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Ciudad">
              </div>
              <div class="p-2">
                <button type="button" class="btn bg-danger text-white">Buscar</button>
              </div>
            </div>

Comment: You may want to reconsider your title, I can see where "double navbar" applies, but I have no idea what this has to do with a directory?

Comment: @DavidThomas this is for a directory that i´m working on, the name of the business and the city it belongs to

Comment: And when we talk about directories here, we tend to think of a computer's directories, folders and so forth. The purpose of the website, or app, is almost entirely irrelevant in this case. The title should focus on the problem, and be concise in its meaning: please, remove the irrelevant and ambiguous reference to "directory."

Comment: Well, now could you please, help me to create that code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example that you can use as a basis.
You can try to play with the borders of your 2 inputs. (`border-left` / `border-right`). You should also modify the `border-radius` of these two inputs.
With this, it will form a single input.

As for putting icons or buttons in the input, you can use the `relative`/`absolute` positions.

Now it's up to you to modify it (like modifying the shadow boxes, input focus, adding your other icons, ...) and to adapt it according to your needs.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <header>
    <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <style lang="scss">
      .buscando {
        border-right-color: white;
        border-radius: 0.25rem 0px 0px 0.25rem;
        margin-right: -2px
      }

      .ciudad {
        border-left-color: white;
        border-radius: 0px 0.25rem 0.25rem 0px;
        margin-left: -5px
      }

      button {
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
      }

    </style>
  </header>

  <body>
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center m-2">
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control buscando shadow-none focus-none"
          placeholder="¿Que Buscas?"
        />
      </div>
      <div class='position-relative'>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control ciudad shadow-none "
          placeholder="Ciudad"
        >

      </input>
      <button
      type="button"
      class="btn bg-danger text-white position-absolute"
      >
      Buscar
    </button>

    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```